# Union Find Algorithm - reading other's code

Tags: python, algorithm, union-find

I was trying to understand the code on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/.

I am not sure whether "parent" in the highlighted part refers to a "defaultdict" object that the user needs to input. Further, could someone explain to me where the "-1" comes from (note that none of the vertices would have value -1)?

[image: Picture]

I apologize for my silly question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is always best to add the code (using the blocktype environment) rather than using screenshots.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about that! I am new to SO.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure whether "parent" in the highlighted part refers to a "defaultdict" object that the user needs to input

No. The `defaultdict` is the graph that the user inputs. `parent` is the tree that represents the sets of connected components of the graph --  it is any tree that connects all nodes from the same connected components. There are multiple ways to construct such a tree, some are better than others

For example, you have a graph consisting of 2 components:

```
1--2
|  |
3--4   5---6
```

The tree (more accurately, the forest) can be

```
  1        5       parent[2] = 1, parent[3] = 1, parent[4] = 3, parent[6] = 5
 / \        \      parent[1] = parent[5] = -1
2   3        6
     \
      4
```

it can also be

```
1         5      parent[2] = 1, parent[3] = 2, parent[4] = 3, parent[6] = 5
 \         \
  2         6    parent[1] = parent[5] = -1
   \
    3
     \
      4
```

The first version is better because the tree is shorter in height. Actually the best tree to represent the component in the above graph is:

```
     1        5
   / | \      |
  2  3  4     6
```

Formally speaking:

- `parent[u] == -1` means u is the root of the tree.
- `parent[u] == v` means u and v belongs to the same connected components.However note that, the reverse is not true: it can be `parent[u] != v` but u and v belongs to the same connected components. Why? Because it can be that `parent[u] == w, parent[w] == v` and u and v are connected by association.
- So how to determine if two nodes u and v are connected? You need to find the roots of the trees that contain u and v, and if the two roots are same then u and v belongs to the same tree and they are connected.
- How to find the root? By going up the parent node until reaching the root (which have a parent of -1)

There are also some tricks to shorten the height of the trees while maintaining its representation. Normally, the height of the union find tree should be and can be kept very short, in the order of log*(N) (with log* is the [iterated log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm))

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanations! How do we represent the following tree as a default dictionary in the example (parent[2] = 1, parent[3] = 1, parent[4] = 3, parent[1] = -1)? Sorry for the silly question. I am not good at programming...

Comment: You can actually make the tree heights even smaller than log* n. The amortized cost of a lookup can be made O(alpha(n)), where alpha(n) is the Ackermann inverse function, which grows even more slowly than log* n.